# How to deploy Keras speech to text model in python

Tags: python, keras

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

# Load saved model
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('best_model_12.hdf5')


def extract_mfccs(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        signal, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=22050)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13)
    return mfccs

# Define function to recognize speech using the model
def recognize_speech(file_path):
    # Extract MFCC features from audio file
    mfccs = extract_mfccs(file_path)
    # Reshape the MFCCs to match the input shape of the model
    mfccs = mfccs.reshape((1, mfccs.shape[0], mfccs.shape[1], 1))
    # Perform speech recognition using the model
    output = model.predict(mfccs)
    # Get the predicted transcription
    transcription = np.argmax(output, axis=2)
    transcription = ''.join([chr(x) for x in transcription[0]])
    return transcription


file_path="Digit Dataset/free-spoken-digit-dataset-master/recordings/0_jackson_0.wav"
transcription = recognize_speech(file_path)
print('Transcription:', transcription)
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 48, 13, 1), found shape=(None, 13, 28, 1)
```

I try this

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
# from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# Load saved model
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('best_model_12.hdf5')
master/recordings/0_jackson_0.wav")

# Define function to extract MFCC features from audio file
def extract_mfccs(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        signal, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=22050)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13)
    return mfccs

# Define function to recognize speech using the model
def recognize_speech(file_path):
    # Extract MFCC features from audio file
    mfccs = extract_mfccs(file_path)
    # Reshape the MFCCs to match the input shape of the model
    mfccs = mfccs.reshape((1, mfccs.shape[0], mfccs.shape[1], 1))
    # Perform speech recognition using the model
    output = model.predict(mfccs)
    # Get the predicted transcription
    transcription = np.argmax(output, axis=2)
    transcription = ''.join([chr(x) for x in transcription[0]])
    return transcription


file_path="Digit Dataset/free-spoken-digit-dataset-master/recordings/0_jackson_0.wav"
transcription = recognize_speech(file_path)
print('Transcription:', transcription)
```

and expected to get a speech but it will not detect the speech and give the error

```
ValueError: Input shape mismatch: expected (48, 13, 1), got (21, 13, 1)
```

also the model is working fine and accuracy is 95% and the model also predict the transcript when I tested but when I loaded the model in another file it gives me above error please help me